# An `aligned` command ignored in a node in a `TikZ` diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the contents of three nodes in an `aligned` environment. Why is it right aligned? I have the `&` before the first character of the first line.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,arrows.meta,bending}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textwidth}{6.1in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textheight}{9in}



\begin{document}


\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize,
execute at begin node={\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0.75ex}%
\setlength\belowdisplayskip{0.5ex}%
\setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0.75ex}%
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0.5ex}}},
shorten/.style={shorten >=#1,shorten <=#1},
pics/fpic/.style={code={#1}}, x=1.5cm, y=1.5cm]

%A sequence of graphs is drawn, starting with the vertex with the b-label b.

\matrix[row sep=4.5em]{%<--- This defines the difference between pictures.
%Here is the blow-up of the vertex labeled b.
\pic{fpic={%
\draw[fill] (-4,0) circle (1.5pt);
\node[anchor=north] (label_for_Vertex_b) at ($(-4,0) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b}};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-4,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
}};\\
%
%
\pic{fpic={%
\draw (-4,0) -- (-2,0) coordinate(lcompare);
\draw[fill] (-4,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (-2,0) circle (1.5pt);
%
\node[anchor=north] (bcompare) at ($(-4,0) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b}};
\node[anchor=south] (label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b) at ($(-4,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] (label_for_Vertex_b-1) at ($(-2,0) +(0,-0.25)$){$b - 1$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-2,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{1}{1}$};
%
%A "pin" is drawn between the midpoint of the first edge and its label.
\coordinate (label_for_first_Edge) at (-3,0);
\draw[draw=gray, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (-3,-0.5) -- (label_for_first_Edge);
\node[anchor=north, align=center, inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize] at (-3,-0.5){$\begin{aligned}&2\bigl[b+(b-1)\bigr] \\[-1ex]
&\qquad=2^{2}b-2
\end{aligned}$};
}}; \\
%
%
\pic{fpic={%
%Here is the blow-up of the vertex labeled b-1.
\draw (-4,0) -- (-2,0) -- (0,0);
\draw[fill] (-4,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (-2,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-4,0) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b}};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-4,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-2,0) +(0,-0.25)$){$b - 1$};
\node[anchor=south] (label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b-1) at ($(-2,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{1}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] (label_for_Vertex_b-2) at ($(0,0) +(0,-0.25)$){$b - 2$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(0,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{2}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-3,0) +(0,-0.1)$){$2^{2}b - 2$};
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-1,0) +(0,-0.1)$){$2^{2}b - 6$};
}}; \\
%
%
\pic{fpic={
%Here is the blow-up of the vertex labeled b-n.
\draw (-4,0) -- (-2,0) -- (0,0) (2,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[fill] (-4,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (-2,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
\node (first_ellipses) at (1,0){$\ldots$};
\coordinate (tail_for_bent_arrow_below_first_ellipses) at ($(first_ellipses) +(0,-0.25)$);
\draw[fill] (2,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (5,0) circle (1.5pt);
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-4,0) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b}};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-4,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-2,0) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-1$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-2,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{1}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(0,0) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-2$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(0,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{2}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=south] (label_for_phantom_Farey_Fraction_at_ellipses) at ($(1,0) +(0,0.25)$){\hphantom{$\dfrac{1}{1}$}};
\coordinate (point_just_above_node_containing_phantom_Farey_Fraction) at ($(label_for_phantom_Farey_Fraction_at_ellipses.north) +(0,0.1)$);
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(2,0) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-n$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(2,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{n}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(5,0) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-(n+1)$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(5,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{n+1}{1}$};
%
%
%
%
%A dashed arrow is drawn to the midpoint of the edge between last two vertices.
\draw[-latex, dashed, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=3mm, shorten >=1mm, overlay] ($(3.5,0) +(60:1.625)$) -- (3.5,0);
\path node[anchor=south, align=center, text width={width("future vertex")}, overlay] at ($(3.5,0) +(60:1.625)$)
{future mediant\\for vertex\[\dfrac{2n+1}{2}\]};
%
%A "pin" is drawn between the midpoint of the last edge and its label.
\coordinate (label_for_Edge) at ($(3.5,-0.5) +(0,-0.75)$);
\draw[draw=gray, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (3.5,0) -- (label_for_Edge);
\node[anchor=north, align=center, inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize] (edge label) at (label_for_Edge){$\begin{aligned}&\text{Present edge label of} \\[-1ex]
&\quad2\bigl[(b-n)+\bigl(b-(n+1)\bigr)\bigr] \\[-1ex]
&\qquad=2^{2}b-2(2n+1)
\end{aligned}$};
}}; \\
\pic{fpic={
%Here is the vertex placed at the broken edge.
\draw (-4,0) -- (-2,0) -- (0,0) (2,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[fill] (-4,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (-2,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
\node (second_ellipses) at (1,0){$\ldots$};
\coordinate (head_for_bent_arrow_above_second_ellipses) at ($(second_ellipses) +(0,0.75)$);
\draw[fill] (2,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] ({(2+5)/2},0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (5,0) circle (1.5pt);
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-4,0) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b}};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-4,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-2,0) +(0,-0.25)$){$b - 1$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-2,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{1}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(0,0) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-2$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(0,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{2}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(2,0) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-n$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(2,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{n}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(5,0) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-(n+1)$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(5,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{n+1}{1}$};
%
%A "pin" is drawn between the midpoint of the last edge and its label.
\draw[draw=gray, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] ({(2+5)/2},0) -- ({(2+5)/2},-0.75);
\node[anchor=north] at ({(2+5)/2},-0.75){$2^{2}b-(2n+1)2$};
\node[anchor=south] (f2n) at ($({(2+5)/2},0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{2n+1}{2}$};
%
\draw[draw=gray, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] ({(3*2+5)/4},0) -- ({(3*2+5)/4-0.75*sqrt(2)},{-0.75*sqrt(2)});
\node[anchor=north east, align=center, inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize] at ({(3*2+5)/4-0.75*sqrt(2)},{-0.75*sqrt(2)})
{$\begin{aligned}&2\bigl[(b-n)+\bigl(2^{2}b-(2n+1)\bigr)2\bigr] - \bigl(b-(n+1)\bigr) \\[-1ex]
&=3^{2}b-3(3n+1)
\end{aligned}$};
\draw[draw=gray, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] ({(2+3*5)/4},0) -- ({(2+3*5)/4+ (1.5)*1/2},{(1.5)* (-sqrt(3)/2)});
\node[anchor=north, align=center, inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize] at ({(2+3*5)/4+ (1.5)*1/2},{(1.5)* (-sqrt(3)/2)})
{$\begin{aligned}&2\bigl[\bigl(b-(n+1)\bigr)+\bigl(2^{2}b-(2n+1)\bigr)2\bigr] - (b-n) \\[-1ex]
&=3^{2}b-3(3n+2)
\end{aligned}$};
}}; \\
};
%
%
%
%
%Arrows are drawn between the diagrams.
\draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt, shorten=7.5pt] (label_for_Vertex_b) to[bend right=30] node[midway, right=1.5mm, align=center]
{Blow-up of\\vertex \textit{b}} (label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b);
%
\draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt, shorten=7.5pt] (label_for_Vertex_b-1) to[bend right=30] node[midway, right=1.5mm, align=center]
{Blow-up of\\vertex $b - 1$} (label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b-1);
%
\draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt, shorten=7.5pt] (label_for_Vertex_b-2) to[bend right=30] node[pos=1/3, right=1.5mm, align=center]
{Blow-up of more\\\hphantom{\ }vertices} (point_just_above_node_containing_phantom_Farey_Fraction);
%
\draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=7.5pt, shorten >=7.5pt] (tail_for_bent_arrow_below_first_ellipses) to[bend right=30]
(head_for_bent_arrow_above_second_ellipses);
%
%
\node[draw, text width=0.25\linewidth,inner sep=2mm,align=left, below left=5mm] at (current bounding box.north east)
{In each step of the expanding simple graphs,
the vertices are labeled with a fraction and
an \textit{b}-label. The fraction is a Farey
Fraction; it is typeset above each vertex.};
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to be in a multiline box, which can be done using [text width=...] (\parbox} or [align=...] (tabular).

Comment: @John Kormylo Isn't that what I have?  I do have `align=center` as an option to the node command.

Comment: @John Kormylo Here is my first multi-line node command.

Comment: @John Kormylo`\node[anchor=north, align=center] at (-3,-0.5){$\begin{aligned}&2\bigl[b+(b-1)\bigr]\\[-1ex]&\qquad=2^{2}b-2\end{aligned}$};`

Comment: @John Kormylo And I just tried enclosing the contents of the node command with `\begin{minipage}{\textwidth} ... \end{minipage}` and the rendering of it put the contents on the left margin.

Comment: Ah yes, aligned won't work in a tabular either.  If you can get it to work outside TikZ, then it will work in a minipage inside TikZ.  And would you minimize your MWE a bit?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what's going on but I also do not understand the purpose of aligned here. You have the structure `\begin{aligned} & <stuff> \\ & <more stuff> \end{aligned}`. The only purpose of aligned seems to be to have the lines starting on the left. For that you do not need `aligned`.

Comment: @Schrödinger's cat I have a shift of `\qquad` in the second line.

Comment: @Schrödinger's cat I would like the contents of the first node command typeset the same as what `LaTeX` would do with `\begin{align*}&2\bigl[b+(b-1)\bigr] \ \ [-1ex]
&\qquad=2^{2}b-2\end{align*}`.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, and this is why I got confused. You could use `\node[anchor=north, align=left, inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize] at (-3,-0.5){$2\bigl[b+(b-1)\bigr] $\\[-1ex]
$\qquad=2^{2}b-2$};` instead. I do not quite see the rationale for using `align=center` and the `aligned` environment. Also you want to compare the output to what you get for `$\begin{aligned}&2\bigl[b+(b-1)\bigr] \\[-1ex]
&\qquad=2^{2}b-2
\end{aligned}$` in a plain document, i.e. outside of a Ti*k*Z node. It is not aligned as you may think it is.

Comment: Finally, I agree with @JohnKormylo that the example is a bit too extensive. It has *many* different nodes with `aligned` environments as well as lot of stuff that is not related to the problem, so anyone trying to answer this will have to guess what the issue is. What is more, any other user that wants to benefit from the thread will have to look at an enormous code and digest it before they know what's going on. It would IMHO be much better to condense the code to the part that is central here.